# What is the meaning of "get as far as doing something"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What is the meaning of the expression or phrase "get as far as doing something"? For example, what does it mean in this sentence?

> They had got as far as painting the kitchen.

Comment: Please stop adding "thank you" into your post--ELU isn't like a regular forum

Comment: I thought this was just a question of good manners.

Comment: While thanking someone *is* good manners, on ELU (and all sites on SE), it's considered unnecessary and always deleted out

Comment: I didn't know that. Now I'm aware of it:)

Comment: I frequently write thank you at the end of a question at StackOverflow. And at Seasoned Advice or Home Improvement or Motor maintenance, we try to do that too. What's so different about this place?

Comment: @BlessedGeek: We're all about "tough love" here.

Answer (score 2):

It means they have not finished some larger task (such as remodeling the entire house), but only reached the milestone of painting the kitchen

Answer (score 1):

Its use depends on the mood.

hyper

> Our journey had been unbelievable. We had never expected to collect any gold medals, but we got as far as collecting 5 gold medals and a couple of bronzes.

hypo

> It was somewhat embarrassing. Even the ride-the-bus-half-price veterans had made it all the way to mile 10, but we did get as far as mile 7. Rather, we only managed to go as far as mile 7.

expected

> It was a case of dishonest misrepresentation. We were told that we only had to carry the mattress two blocks to have it exchanged in their nearest other outlet. But, we had to go as far as five blocks.